# Fatal error: Out of memory with the Duplicator plugin

Tags: plugins, xampp

When i try to install a website that i got as an duplicator archive i get the following error at the very last step of the installation:

[image]
I am using the latest version of xampp on my local machine which has 16GB of DDR4. These are the relevant values in my PHP.INI

```
memory_limit=1024M
max_execution_time=300
post_max_size=32M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I downgraded my PHP-Version from 7.2.5 to 5.6.36 and that fixed it.

Comment: This is such a stupid solution. Don't do this! Find a way to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I though that this might be due to the size of my MySQL file(5GB). So I selected the advanced option for the database upload which is to upload the database manually. I didn't succeed doing so through the phpMyAdmin interface, instead I imported it through mysql cli with :
`mysql -u username -p database_name < my_file.sql`

Also for more troubleshooting check the official documentation [here](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/faqs-tech/#faq-trouble-100-q).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i figured it out already ;)